# "Намедни" в значении предлога

Tags: наречия

Можно ли употребить слово "намедни" в значении предлога: событие случилось намедни 12-го года?

Comment: Фразу полностью дайте: предлог есть связь слов.

Comment: Вам так хочется, хочется кому-то, и он настаивает на этом «обороте»?

Comment: Мне так хочется, но я сомневаюсь

Answer (score 2):

Обращаемся к [словарям](http://endic.ru/academic/Namedni-23597.html).
**Наме́дни**:
***наречие**, устар. и прост.* Недавно, на днях;
***наречие*** (прост.). Совсем недавно, на днях;
***наречие** разг.-сниж*. На днях, недавно.

Конструкция ***намедни*** (на днях, недавно, совсем недавно) ***12-го года*** невозможна — по определению. Во всех предложениях, представленных в [Нацкорпусе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&startyear=1800&mydocsize=&mysize=&spp=&mysentsize=&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8&mycorp=&endyear=2019&mysent=&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&text=lexform&dpp=&spd=&p=0), слово "намедни" используется только в значении наречия.

Можно, конечно, зацепиться за словарь Даля:
**намедни** — намеднись, намесь, намеднича нареч. надысь, ногдысь, анадысь, номнясь, ономня, онамедни; недавно, ***незадолго***, считая не часами, а днями (оными дни)...
Но наречие [незадо́лго](https://endic.ru/ozhegov/Nezadolgo-18126.html) само употребляется только с предлогом (*до чего* или *перед чем*):
незадолго до 12-го года, незадолго перед 12-м годом.

**Дополнение** (по поводу наращения)
Если имеется в виду **календарная дата** (то есть 12 год до н. э., или 18**12** год, или 20**12** год), то наращение не требуется.
[Когда применять наращения?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)